# Call requiers API level 26 java.time.LocalDate#of

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ни один метод класса LocalDate не могу вызвать, так как для этого нужен минимальный API 26.

У меня:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как тогда работать для API ниже 26?

Comment: может это подойдет - Time time = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
        time.setToNow();

        String date = time.format("%Y:%m:%d");

Answer (score 1):

Класс `LocalDate` появился сравнительно недавно. В Java начиная с версии 1.8, а в Android с API 26. Если вам требуется именно этот класс, то придется ограничится API26, либо использовать другие варианты решений (что именно вам нужно получить в вопросе вы не указали), которые поддерживает минимально необходимый вам API, ведь много лет как то обходились без этого класса.